# Realizing a set as the image of a smooth map

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, resolution-of-singularities

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$S = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |y| \leq |x|^{3/2} \}$

(See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20abs%28y%29%20%3C%3D%20abs%28x%29%5E%283%2F2%29) for a plot on Wolfram Alpha.)

The origin $(0, 0)$ is a kind of singular point of $S$.

**Question:** Does there exist a $C^2$ map $\varphi \colon M \to \mathbb{R}^2$ on some manifold $M$ such that $\varphi(M) = S$?

Further context:

- I would like for $M$ to be finite dimensional.
- Ideas of techniques to construct or disprove the existence of such $\varphi$ are welcome.
- It is satisfactory if the image of $\varphi$ is locally the same as $S$ around the origin.
- The set $S' = \{ (x, y) : y^2 \leq x^3 \}$ is the right-half of $S$; it admits a smooth lift: $\varphi(s, t) = (s^2, s^3 \sin(t))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(s^4\, \text{sign}(s),s^6 \sin t)$.

[image]

---

Or even an infinitely smooth map:

$$(s^2 e^{-2/|s|}\, \text{sign}(s),s^3 e^{-3/|s|} \sin t),$$
with $(0,0)$ for $s=0$.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!